# Loop integral form

Tags: integration, divergence-operator

I'm trying to calculate an integral which looks unfortunately divergent. The structure is similar to a loop integral but the appendix in the Peskin Quantum Field Theory textbook didn't have a useable form. The integral form is (I did a u substitution to make it easier to look at)

$$
\int_x^{\infty}du \frac{u^2}{\omega - u}
$$

Does anyone know of a workable form for this? Introducing a cutoff is possible but I would prefer not to.

Thank you!

Comment: You’re right, this diverges (are those bounds in $u$ coordinates?).   Are you asking how to see the divergence?

Comment: Yes the bounds are in u coordinates. I was hoping that there was a workable form using the $\Gamma(x)$ function like is often used in loop integrals, but the different powers of u in the numerator and denominator are concerning. Maybe there is some regularization technique to remove the divergence under certain parameters (at least that's what I was hoping for)

Comment: It doesn't just look divergent, it **is** divergent, even twice, if $x\le\omega $.

Comment: No, it’s easier than all that:  just long divide.

Comment: @Randall could you explain what you mean by that please?

Comment: Sure, hold on a sec.

Comment: To be honest (and I say this as a theoretical physicist), questions about how to regularize integrals in QFT are probably better-suited to Physics.SE.  There are a lot of implicit assumptions and techniques involved in them that are second nature to physicists but seem bizarre to pure mathematicians.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea, I'll try posting it on the physics forum as well and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The degree of the numerator is greater than the degree of the denominator, which is a signal to do some old-fashioned long division of polynomials.  When you do, you get a quotient of $-u-\omega$ and a remainder of $\omega^2$.  This means that
$$
\frac{u^2}{\omega-u} = -u-\omega +\frac{\omega^2}{\omega-u.}
$$
Now the integral is doable, the last term giving you a logarithm (but the $-u$ term is already a problem as $u \to \infty$).  Can you handle the rest?

**After the fact:** looking at this some more, you may need to be really careful about what $x$ is, making sure that everything makes sense here and is set up correctly.  Again, I'll leave that to you.  So, take my answer as how to get the general antiderivative.

Comment: Thank you I see what you mean; I'm guessing I'll have to do a branch cut on the logarithm function and even then will have divergences from the $-u$ term

Comment: Yes, right, if these are complex variables you will hit the same problem.